# Connecting Power BI report Builder To postgresql

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder

While trying to connect PostgreSQL to power bi report builder ,PostgreSQL connection is not showing in the list how can i connect to the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Power BI Report Builder [Embedded data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-embedded-data-source) Postgresql is not supported, only the following are supported:

Azure Analysis Services

Azure SQL Database

Azure SQL Data Warehouse (now Azure Synapse Analytics)

SQL Server

SQL Server Analysis Services

Oracle

Teradata